# How to send SendEnv variable to sftp session using java

Tags: session-variables

I want to send `SendEnv` variable to `sftp session` using java code.

How can I achieve this using java? It can be done using command prompt as follows:

```
export RDIR=4
sftp -o SendEnv=RDIR user@<hostname>
```